# Linux kernel module: calling up on semaphore causes null pointer dereference

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to learn Linux kernel module development, and following the book "Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition". I'm trying to implement a memory-only device like scull, opening and closing the device with `open` and `close` in userspace works fine, but my `read` and `write` implementations aren't working. In the function that initializes a new device when the module is first loaded, I create the semaphore like this:

```c
// ...
struct semaphore *sema;

sema = kmalloc(sizeof(struct semaphore), GFP_KERNEL);
sema_init(sema, 1);

my_device->sem = *sema;
```

`my_device` is the device struct containing the `cdev` struct and other things.

In my `write` implementation, I have

```c
ssize_t my_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
    // ...
    struct MyDev *dev = filp->private_data; // MyDev is the struct initialized above
    if (down_interruptible(&dev->sem))
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to get semaphore\n");
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
    }
```

That part works fine, as does writing data to the device. But when I call

```c
up(&dev->sem);
```

at the end, I get `Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000000007a4`.

The kernel "oops" is `Internal error: Oops: 96000004 [#1]` and the trace is:

```
Call trace:
__raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x3c/0xa0
try_to_wake_up+0x50/0x674
wake_up_process+0x24/0x30
__up.isra.0+0x58/0x70
up+0x68/0x70
my_write+0x250/0x2dc [devices]     // my function
vfs_write+0xfc/0x2c0
ksys_write+0x74/0x100
__arm64_sys_write+0x28/0x34
invoke_syscall+0x50/0x120
el0_svc_common+0x48/0x100
do_el0_svc+0x34/0xa0
el0_svc+0x2c/0x54
el0t_64_sync_handler+0xe8/0xf0
el0t_64_sync+0x198/0x19c
Code: aa1303e0 52800001 52800022 2a0103e3 (88e37e62)
```

If it's relevant, my `file_operations` struct looks like this

```c
static struct file_operations my_ops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = my_open,
    .release = my_close,
    .read = my_read,
    .write = my_write,
};
```

Is it possible the kernel is looking for other functions on that struct that I haven't defined yet? I have logged out all the pointers used in `my_write` and I know they're not null. Why does `down_interruptible` work but not `up`?

Edit: I also tried just `down` instead of `down_interruptible` - `down` also works, but `up` still doesn't.

And just for completeness, here is the entire `my_write`

```c
ssize_t my_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    struct MyDev *dev = filp->private_data;
    struct MySet *dptr;
    int quantum = dev->quantum;
    int qset = dev->qset;
    int itemsize = quantum * qset;
    int item, s_pos, q_pos, rest;
    ssize_t retval = -ENOMEM;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "about to get semaphore dev->sem %p\n", &dev->sem);

    if (down_interruptible(&dev->sem))
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to get semaphore\n");
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
    }

    printk(KERN_ALERT "got past semaphore\n");

    item = (long)*f_pos / itemsize;
    rest = (long)*f_pos % itemsize;
    s_pos = rest / quantum;
    q_pos = rest % quantum;

    dptr = my_follow(dev, item);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "after follow, dptr: %p\b", dptr);

    if (dptr == NULL)
        goto out;

    if (!dptr->data)
    {
        dptr->data = kmalloc(qset * sizeof(char *), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!dptr->data)
            goto out;
        memset(dptr->data, 0, qset * sizeof(char *));
        printk(KERN_ALERT "zeroed dptr->data\n");
    }



    if (!dptr->data[s_pos])
    {
        dptr->data[s_pos] = kmalloc(quantum, GFP_KERNEL);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "allocated mem for dptr->data[%d]\n", s_pos);
        if (!dptr->data[s_pos])
            goto out;
    }

    if (count > quantum - q_pos)
        count = quantum - q_pos;

    if (copy_from_user(dptr->data[s_pos] + q_pos, buf, count))
    {
        retval = -EFAULT;
        goto out;
    }

    printk(KERN_ALERT "copied from user\n");

    *f_pos += count;
    retval = count;

    if (dev->size < *f_pos)
        dev->size = *f_pos;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "calling up...\n");

out:
    up(&dev->sem);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "called up, returning %zx\n", retval);
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: `my_device->sem = *sema;` - By that line you **copy** semaphore **structure**, which is never intended to work. If your device structure has field `struct semaphore sem;` then you can initialize it with `sema_init(&dev->my_device, 1);`. Allocation (`kmalloc`) of the semaphore is needed only when you store **pointer** to it.

Comment: You should also check that kmalloc isn't returning NULL.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it worked! Thanks for the explanation. I think you answered my last driver question too haha